# C# Setup Project run after install

Tags: c#, installation, project

Hello guys I'm new to the forum also programming and need some help about a project.

So I recently start developing a program that firstly must add its path at the end of Registry => Environment => Path.
For this job I created project (MainLogic) which contain a class (Program) that do the job, Installer Class that contains this events below and configured Setup Project. [SOURCE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis)

```
    public InstallerClass1()            
    {            
        this.Committed += InstallerClass1_Committed;
        this.Committing += InstallerClass1_Committing;
    }

    private void InstallerClass1_Committing(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("");
        //Console.WriteLine("Committing Event occurred.");
        //Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    private void InstallerClass1_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName
            (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(
              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\MainLogic.exe");
    }
```

The program was installed correctly but MainLogic.exe file I call after installation cause an error and can't start. The exception is Null Reference at `MainLogic.Program.Main(String[] args)`

Here is a picture for better understanding -

[image]

Is there a way to avoid that exception or could you offer me another that will work.

*** Here what i found. I can execute creating and typing in to file. Writing on the console. Probably a lot of other stuff without problem. But when try to execute this peace of code which actually I have to use...

```
    Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Pass Key", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree).SetValue("Finaly", "Done");
    Registry.CurrentUser.Close();
```

...the exception I described above occurs. Suggestions?

---

So the main reason for all those "exercises" is because I want to implement ffmpeg in my application.
I guess you are hear about ffmpeg (a video/audio processing program that works in command prompt). 
So what I'm working on is to implement it in my project for mp3 extracting from video files but I wanna make it more user friendly so the user can pass commands through GUI and from there my code should do the other job. So ffmpeg works through command prompt (I know there is a wrappers but I'm not very satisfied with what read about) but firstly you have to add his path to Path's value in the registry. And here's where my problem came from.

Maybe it's sounds stupid for you but you know.. when you start something make it all the way.

Comment: Registry can be manipulated using Setup itself.

Comment: And it should be, as the program will probably not run with admin rights after the setup is done.

Comment: The exception is thrown inside of your main. Look what you do there.

Comment: @SarveshMishra It is true but you can only add new Keys and Values there. What I want to do is to edit the Path's value data with the currently installed program path which I get in the Installer class. With the way you suggested operation seems to be impossible.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar so is there a way to run it as administrator in Committed event?

Comment: @zisov4eto You need to google [TARGETDIR]MyExe.exe "To shoot an arrow in the dark" is not what I usually do.

Comment: @gismo i don't think the problem is IN the main method because running the program independently does the job without exceptions.

Comment: as @marc-wittman said, try with a try/catchblock to see what causes the exception. That the exception doesnt occur in the release version is all the more reason.

Comment: @gismo you were right. The problem is becouse of the code in there. Check the post update.

Comment: @zisov4eto try to put the registry handle in a var, then edit it, then close it. I am not familiar with the registry. But there has to be a different behavior in debug then in the release version. Maybe in debug, you dont actually get a real handle to the registry but to a front. Put a breakpoint there and look up what it is actually doing in memory.

Comment: @gismo Everything works fine in debug and release mode when I execute the project separately from setup project.
Even with variable to hold the registry the same error occurs after the install.

Comment: @zisov4eto You can add the current installation path to the registry with the setup itself. http://codinglight.blogspot.de/2008/08/installing-startup-registry-key-in.html. Question is: Do you really need the path in the registry or can you determine it at runtime?

Comment: @zisov4eto This sounds like, you use a selection string that does not exist.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The thing is that the Path value already exist and its not empty. So I want to keep all the data in it and just attach one my path after.
Do I really need this? 
This operation must be executed only ones when the program is installed. I don't want to check on every start of the program if the data of the current value contains specified path.
Can you suggest better way to do that?

Comment: @gismo if you mean "Pass Key" no, its there and working outside the setup project.

Comment: If you want to control ffmpeg through your own application you don't really need to have it in the path. Only *your* application needs to know where it is. You call `Process.Start` to run the command line, which should then include the full path. If ffmpeg is in the same folder as your application, you will get this path using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`. Please be aware of license implications of installing ffmpeg along with your application!

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar now i remember something. The "How To" of ffmpeg says that IF YOU WANT to use it from every directory in your computer add the .exe path into Environment Paths... Unfortunately I forgot about this when I came with the idea to create something like this. Thank you very much buddy. And about the license is there a way to use the program legally along with mine? I'm not very familiar with this kind of stuffs.

Comment: Not sure whether this is the right place for legal questions ;-) I actually don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If course you can just add exception handling and see what goes wrong but you don`t neet that anyway. Try to set the registry key directly in your Installer

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class Installer1 : Installer
{
    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);

        const string key_path = "SOFTWARE\\YourCompany\\YourApplication";
        const string key_value_name = "InstallationDirectory";

        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (key == null)
        {
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(key_path);
        }

        string tgt_dir = "someDirectory";

        key.SetValue(key_value_name, tgt_dir);

    }
```

if you want to alter the path enironment variables set the key there. You can simply add a new variable or look for an exiting one (including the value) for example with *Registry.GetValue* [MSDN-Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

User Variables

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

System Variables

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Comment: What if I want want to inspect the MSI to see what registry changes it will do?

Comment: You mean if the uinstaller wants to check for existing reg values? You can easily do that.. or do you mean something different?

Comment: By Inspection of MSI, I mean analyzing the content of MSI. If registry is manipulated in custom actions, these can't be detected in advance. And if something can be done transparently and easily in simpler way then why complicate the process.

Comment: @MarcWittmann I tried your way but more simplified like this Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Pass Key", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree).SetValue("Finaly", "Done"); 

Again thrown an exception but this time program didn't finish instaling.
Tried same thing in the Commit method = same result.

Comment: just include a try catch before your registry processing and messageBox where the nullPointer comes from
yes, depending on framework version you can simplyfy it.. just wanted to give you a hint

Comment: @MarcWittmann So what i did is to put Registry operations in try-catch in the main method of the project and I tried to get the message, stack trace, source and inner exception. But the information is nothing much then the one in he screenshot.
Interesting thing is when I run the project separately from setup project everything works fine.
Even when I try to execute some other action after install like, writing into text file, again its work.

Comment: @MarcWittmann I wonder what the advantage of this is over simply using the Visual Studio Installer Registry UI to set a registry key to `[TargetDirectory]`...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Please show me example of how to this because obviously i don't understand. Show example of how to add data for Path value in CURRENT_USER without deleting any of previous data in that value. I'll be grateful

Comment: @zisov4eto You're trying this on `CURRENT_USER`? What if another user tries to use the installed application? He won't get the new path value then? Maybe it's time you actually described your real requirement in the question so we don't have to fit together bits and pieces of information... Maybe you should read up on how to use a setup to update the **global** (all users) path variable...

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar didn`t use that feature often and I´m not sure how to manipulate existing keys (check exiting key and react on the value) and that is what OP wanted somehow. If you can achieve this with the installer UI I´m sure it would be a good solution!

Comment: @zisov4eto so the innerException.Message is a nullPointerException? Be sure not to generate that exception when trying to access an innerException that is not there!
Do it like that String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) 
                      ? ex.InnerException.Message
                      : "NO INNER EXCEPTION!";

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar to be more clear I have made an update of my question. You can check it. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @zisov4eto I'll write another comment to the question to address your real problem :-)